# Внутренний сервер роутера ZXHN H118N

Tags: веб-сервер, роутер

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Такая ситуация - есть роутер ZXHN H118N (с прошивкой `Дом.ру`). По адресу `192.168.0.1` открывается стандартный веб-интерфейс роутера. Также данный интерфейс открывается и по текущему ip адресу, который выдал провайдер. То есть при попытке обратиться к текущему ip роутер перенаправляет запрос на веб интерфейс.

Есть ли возможность как-то убрать привязку IP адреса к веб-интерфейсу, а оставить только на `192.168.0.1`?